# Relacion Multiple en Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

como puedo realcionar 2 tablas con una, os explico, tengo una tabla works y otra projects, estas dos tablas tienen en común una tabla que se llama events, donde quiero poner como fk el id y el tipo ya que se pueden repetir los id (id 1 de works o projects por ejemplo). Anteriormente la tenia relacionada solo con la tabla works, pero he tenido que añadir projects, entonces he añadido el campo type a events para poder diferenciar. Como seria la relación en la migración y el modelo. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

En tu modelo events, tienes que hacer la relación de las dos tablas, sería algo como esto.

Dependiendo del tipo de relación que tenga la tabla ya sea uno a uno, uno a muchos, muchos a muchos, tendrias que cambiar la clausula hasMany por la que corresponda al tipo de relación

```
  <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Events extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'events';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = ['id','campo1', 'campo2', 'campo3', 'campo4'];

    public function works(){
        //Este sería tu modelo works que apunta a dicha tabla
        return $this->hasMany('App\Works', 'id');
    }

    public function projects(){
        //Este sería tu modelo projects que apunta a dicha tabla
        return $this->hasMany('App\Projects','id');
    }
}
```

Comment: El modelo en **Singular**  . `Event `

Answer (score 0):

Gracias, así tengo el modelo, pero con belong to

```
public function work()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Work', 'parent_id', 'parent_type');
}

// Relaciono el evento con su proyecto
public function project()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Project', 'parent_id', 'parent_type');
}
```

Con respecto a la migración, como sería añadiendo 2 tablas en la referencia.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('events', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->date('date');
        $table->time('time');
        $table->string('place', 200);
        $table->string('city', 100);
        $table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('works')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->integer('parent_type')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('parent_type')->references('id')->on('works')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```